# responsive div for div size, not just window size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive div structure that is collapsing when the window gets to 525px breakpoint:

```
.data-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.data-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 525px) {
  .data-column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to limit also the size of the parent div width to make it collapse, same way as it works with the window width?

So if I will use it inside a small component, the .data-column will collapse and will be shown as 'mobile view' automatically, even when the whole window is still desktop big.

I tried something like that:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 525px) or parent-div and (min-width: 525px) {
  .data-column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

If something was not clear please let me know so I can edit the question and describe it better.

Comment: What you're looking for doesn't exist. if you set a min-width on `.data-column`, however, you can ensure that columns will collapse if they would be too small in their container; which is the more correct approach to take anyways

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve the problem with CSS.   Are you open to a JavaScript solution?  Can you make your code run in a stack snippet or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Media queries for container width don't exist right now. The more correct approach to achieve what you are going for would be to put a `min-width` on your inner element:

```css
.data-column {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think they don't exist now?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS because it doesnt? what kind of question is that? if you think I'm wrong and a media query based on a __parent *element*__ `min-width` exists, provide it

Comment: I didn't think you were wrong and I think your insight was helpful.  +1 for you.  I was just curious.  I've seen CSS grow over the last 20 years and like to think about why it is growing the way that it is.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS ah, sorry I misinterpreted what you were actually asking. I think the *reason* they don't exist is because there really isn't enough of a practical use that isn't covered by just adding a `min-width` or `max-width` to the child element itself to justify the extreme level of complexity that parsing, processing and rendering an element-size-based media query would require to implement

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be looking for something more like:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 525px), (width: 525px) {
  .data-column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

More about media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: its invalid css and makes logically no sense. why use a min width if an in correct added statment ask for a specific definite width afterwards? YOu dont split media queries rules with a comma, you always need to use ' and' . Which makes your CSS invalid

Comment: I was under the impression, as per the linked w3schools article, that the comma-separated syntax is valid and is effectively an OR condition. I don't disagree that there's probably a better logical solution for this situation, but was just trying to address OP's question.

Comment: its valid but its redundant. it says width >= 525 or 525, but 525 is already included in >=525. Also, OP said they have already figured out how to make it responsive at the 525 breakpoint, which is what this answer does. This does not address how to make it responsive with respect to the parent div which is what OP is asking

Comment: yes a comma can be used for an or condition which makes no sense however. You rule is: width of  `525 pixel or above` or `525 pixels`. In this case it is already included in the first statement so it cant be an `or` as `or` would require a differend rule. Which makes your rule set even more invalid

Comment: @tacoshy its not "senseless" nor "invalid," its just redundant

Comment: The end goal should be reduced and concise code.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. I should have considered the broader context of their intentions.